# Writing Scope for Associations using JOINS - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I would like to write a scope that displays users that are within a
>   `"Management Group"` or an `"Event Management Group"`
>
> could one kindly advise me how this is written.

I can successfully display users in a "Management Group" by writing the below scope:

```
user.rb

scope :hosts, ->() { joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name' => "Management Group") }
```

> how would i write a scope that display users in both "Management
>   Group" and "Event Management Group"

I tried the below but doesn't work:

```
scope :hosts, ->() { joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name' =>  "Event Management Group") && joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name' =>  "Management Group") }
```

I also tried the below but no luck:

```
scope :hosts, ->() { joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name ? OR', "Event Management Group", "Management Group") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IN`

```
scope :hosts, -> { joins(:category_managementgroup).where("category_managementgroups.name IN (?)", ["Management Group", "Event Management Group"]) }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just use activerecord syntax properly and you will get what you are expecting

```
scope :hosts, -> { 
  joins(:category_managementgroup)
    .where(category_managementgroups: { name: ["Event Management Group", "Management Group"] }) 
}
```

This scope will give you the users who are in `Event Management Group` Or `Management Group`.

Comment: @ARTLoe this query will generate IN query. its the rails way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work:

```
scope :hosts, ->() { joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name' =>  "Event Management Group").joins(:category_managementgroup).where('category_managementgroups.name' =>  "Management Group") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should break out your other scopes

User.rb

```
scope :hosts_in_any_management, -> { joins(:category_managementgroup).merge(CategoryMangagementgroup.in_management)}

scope :hosts_in_both_management_groups, -> { joins(:category_managementgroup).merge(CategoryMangagementgroup.both_management_groups) }
```

CategoryManagementgroup.rb

```
scope :in_management, -> { management_group.or(CategoryManagementgroup.event_management_group) }

scope :both_management_groups, -> { event_management_group.management_group }

scope :event_management_group, -> { where name: 'Event Management Group'}
scope :management_group, -> { where name: 'Management Group' }
```